# Is the following envelope listStatus, listRecipients requests a polling limit violation

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I have the following process:

Every 20 minutes and for every not completed envelope that I have, I make a listStatus request
and immediately after a listRecipients request for the envelope.
If an envelope is signed and completed then I make a getDocument request.

After I went through all the envelopes, I wait 20 minutes until I make the next round of requests.

Is this case  an API violation?

Comment: Consult their documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not an API violation, but it's not a best practice either.
The best way to get status information about an envelope is to use the [DocuSign Connect Webhook](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/). This way you don't have to use timers, have delays, or risk API violations.
The webhook can be done for a specific envelope, or for the entire account, and it can provide information about the envelope beyond just status.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that it's not the best practice, but it is what I was asked to do.